# GridBagLayout: equally distributed cells

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Is it possible to completely emulate the behavior of a GridLayout with the GridBagLayout manager?

Basically, I have a 8x8 grid in which each cell should have the same width and height. The GridLayout automatically did this. But I want to add another row and column to the grid which size is *not the same* as the other ones. That row/column should take up all the remaining space that might be left over (because the available size couldn't be equally distributed into 8 cells). Is that even possible, or do I – again – have to use a different layout manager?

#### edit

Here is a simple graphic of what I want to achieve, simplified to just 4 cells:
[image: Problem graphic]

The colored cells are the ones I added to the actual grid (gray) which has cells with the same height and width `x`. So the grid's height and width is `4*x`. I now want the additional cells to have the necessary width/height (minimumSize) plus the rest of the available width/height from the full size.

If the whole panel's size is changed, the gray grid cells should again take up as much as space as possible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After trying many different things with the built-in layout managers, I decided to create a custom layout manager for this problem as well. I didn't do it yet, as I didn't have the time to continue with this project, but when I have it done, I'll make sure to post the layout manager code here, so that anyone interested in a similar solution can use it.

#### edit

*didxga* reminded me in the comments that I wanted to post my solution. However, after digging out the project from back then and looking at it, I actually cannot post my solution because it turns out that I never got to creating it!

It was a uni project that finished official mid September 2010. We actually wanted to continue working on it afterwards, which is probably why I said that I would post it (as that was one thing I wanted to improve), but we never really got around doing it – sadly. Instead I simply left out those extra column and row (which was meant as a label for the rows/columns btw).

So yeah, I’m terribly sorry that I cannot post a layout that does what I initially wanted… :( Maybe if there are enough requesting such a layout, I would create it, but as of now, I’m not really willing to dive into Java layouting again ;)

Comment: You forgot to post it, didn't you? :)

Comment: @didxga Good point, I totally forgot about this. I’ll try to dig that one out, and edit my answer :)

Comment: +1 I :-) don't understand :-) whats going on, simple without any issue with GridBadLayout, SpringLayout or e.g., eeeeght especially alive too old thread by downvoting (some changes in LayoutManagers APIs)

Comment: @mKorbel making your own LayoutManager is almost invariably a bad idea. It tends to work except when it doesn't, e.g. when you change surrounding layout constraints, or when a new version of Swing assumes more things that a LayoutManager does that the home-cooked LayoutManager doesn't observer - and you won't notice except in the corner cases where the new interpretation actually matters. It's a good way to make your code brittle, unless you're invested into keeping the LayoutManager up with all news about Swing.

Answer (score 3):

set `weightx` and `weighty` of `GridBagConstraints` of the fixed cells to `0` and the `fill` to `NONE`. For the floating cells set `fill` to `BOTH`, for the floating cells that should expand only horizontally set `weightx` to `1` and for the vertically expanding ones set `weighty` to `1`.

The cells only expand if they have any content, so you need to fill it with something. I chose `JLabel`s and set fixed dimensions for the labels in the fixed cells. On resize you need to recalculate the dimensions and call `invalidate()` to recalculate the layout.

Here is an example for a `w` x `h` grid:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class GridBag {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Gridbag Test");
        final Container c = f.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        final Dimension dim = new Dimension(70, 70);
        final int w = 4;
        final int h = 4;
        final JLabel[] yfloating = new JLabel[w];
        final JLabel[] xfloating = new JLabel[h];
        final JLabel[][] fixed = new JLabel[w][h];

        // adding the vertically floating cells
        final GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gc.weightx = 0.0;
        gc.weighty = 1.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
            yfloating[i] = new JLabel("floating " + i);
            yfloating[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            yfloating[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            yfloating[i].setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            gc.gridy = 0;
            gc.gridx = i+1;
            c.add(yfloating[i], gc);
        }

        // adding the horizontally floating cells
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gc.weightx = 1.0;
        gc.weighty = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
            xfloating[i] = new JLabel("floating " + i);
            xfloating[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            xfloating[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            xfloating[i].setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            gc.gridy = i+1;
            gc.gridx = 0;
            c.add(xfloating[i], gc);
        }

        // adding the fixed cells
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gc.weightx = 0.0;
        gc.weighty = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < h; ++j) {
                fixed[i][j] = new JLabel("fixed " + i);
                fixed[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                fixed[i][j].setMaximumSize(dim);
                fixed[i][j].setMinimumSize(dim);
                fixed[i][j].setPreferredSize(dim);

                gc.gridx = i+1;
                gc.gridy = j+1;
                c.add(fixed[i][j], gc);
            }
        }

        c.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                final Component comp = e.getComponent();
                final int newSize = Math.min(comp.getHeight() / h, comp.getWidth() / w);
                final Dimension newDim = new Dimension(newSize, newSize);
                for(int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < h; ++j) {
                        fixed[i][j].setMaximumSize(newDim);
                        fixed[i][j].setMinimumSize(newDim);
                        fixed[i][j].setPreferredSize(newDim);
                    }
                }
                comp.invalidate();
            }
        });

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not tied to the GridBagLayout necessarily, you should look into the [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com) library. You can do something along the lines of:

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout(
        "",         // Layout Constraints
        "[10][10][10][10]", // Column constraints
        "[10][10][10][10]");  // Row constraints
```

Comment: After reading the quick start guide for this layout manager, I think this is basically what GridBagLayout wishes it was. It works like GridBagLayout, but it seems much more simple and well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

All values are set in the `GridBagConstraints`.

If you want your 8x8 grid fixed, you can set the `ipadx` and `ipady` values.

Then set the `weightx` and `weighty` values of your new row/column to `1.0` and set `fill` to `FULL`.

Your extra row/column will expand with the space that is left over.

If you want the 8x8 grid to expand as well, that is more complicated. You can adjust the `ipadx` and `ipady` values in addition to the `weightx` and `weighty` values. Or make a panel for the 8x8 grid and use a `GridLayout` in there. Use your `GridBagLayout` on the panel and the additional row/column.

Comment: Yes, I want the actual grid to expand as necessary, with 8 cells per row/column equal size and the 9th cell some minimum width/height + the rest of the available width/height. I'm not sure if the extra panel will work, as the additional row should have 9 cells with the same width as the rest of the grid, and the additional column 9 cells with the same height. Basically the additional row/column is supposed to contain labels for the cells.

Comment: Set `fill` to `FULL`? There is no `FULL` constant in `GridBagConstraints` (and no `FILL` neither).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not doing this in a JTable?  Seems like just the sort of thing it's made for.  With the appropriate cell renderer you can put anything you want in the cells.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/TableRowHeaderExample.htm