# Different row color in gridbag layout

Tags: java, awt

How do i set different color for different row in GridBagLayout?

P.S : I cannot use swing in my app as client requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695402/gridbaglayout-equally-distributed-cells

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509781/java-gridbaglayout-automated-construction

Comment: *"I cannot use swing in my app as client requirement."*  Those dang timelords and their fussiness.  What, are they off to 1998? ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson not, some schools still have a 'curriculum' in Java AWT

Answer (score 1):

for AWT works `setBackground(Color)` too

Answer (score 1):

A GridBagLayout has nothing to do with the color of any row or component added to a panel that uses a GridBadLayout as the layout manager. If you want different color rows, then you need to create a separate panel for every row of components and set the background color of the panel.